# Latex table with double thick and thin lines

Tags: tables, addlines

I would like to create the following table. But I'm stuck something is always throwing me off. I can't achieve this table. Packages are interfearing or line are cut.
[image]

Thanks for any help

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE, please an MWE of what you have tried so-far. Please note that this is not a `just-do-it-for-me` site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following might serve as a starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{boldline}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|cV{2.7}c|}
\hline
D & C & B & A & S\\
\hline\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & - \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & - \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & - \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & - \\
\hlineB{2.7}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & - \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Top doble line is stil but but otherwise very easy simple and he syntax is not too heavy for big tables. Thanks you very much

Answer (score 2):

I have provided code and example for your tabular using both standard `tabular` environment, and using the package [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals). The challenge is to avoid that the horizontal double rules between row 1 and row 2 overwrite the vertical lines. Be aware that the rules when using `tabular` and [hhline](https://ctan.org/pkg/hhline) may look different in different PDF-viewers.

### CALS-table

Here is a solution using the [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals)-packages. Since you can turn on and off rules, including thickness, per cell in `calstable`, it is possible to typeset your table without broken lines.

1. I have simulated the double line between row 1 and 2 by setting a very narrow row (2pt) using the command:

   ```
   \ht\cals@current@row=2pt
   ```

   since `calstable` does not support double rules. I have removed the top padding from all cells in that row, but I run into some problem when removing the bottom padding. Therefore, you will get some warnings regarding `Overfull hboxes`. Just ignore them.
2. The heavy horizontal rules are typeset using an `on/off` command (`\bbb` – Bold Bottom Border) setting the the bottom border to `1.5pt`. This command will be in effect until it is switched off at the end of the row.
3. The vertical, heavy rules (the border) are typeset with a similar command (`\brb` – Bold Right Border) switching on and off the heavy rule at the beginning and end of the affected cells. It is a little bit more tedious do set the vertical rules, because [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals) do not have a command that effects all cell in a row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cals}

\begin{document}

\begin{calstable}[c]
% Defining 12 equal columns
\colwidths{{24pt}{24pt}{24pt}{24pt}{24pt}{24pt}{24pt}{24pt}{24pt}{24pt}{24pt}{24pt}
            }

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.3pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.3pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.3pt}
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.3pt}             % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.3pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}

\def\bbb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Bold Bottom Border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderB{1.5pt}
\else \let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

\def\brb{\ifx\cals@borderR\relax     % Bold Right Border switch (off-on)
\def\cals@borderR{1.5pt}
\else \let\cals@borderR\relax\fi}

\def\tp{\ifdim\cals@paddingT=0.0pt\relax    % Top padding switch (off-on)
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingT}{0pt}\fi}

\def\bp{\ifdim\cals@paddingB=0.0pt\relax    % Bottom padding switch (off-on)
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingB}{0pt}\fi}

% R1H1
\thead{\itshape\large%
\brow
    \alignC\cell{D}
    \cell{C}
    \cell{B}
    \brb\cell{A}\brb  % Switch on and off heavy vertical rule for this cell
    \cell{S}
    \brb\cell{T}\brb
    \cell{U}
    \brb\cell{V}\brb
    \cell{W}
    \brb\cell{X}\brb
    \cell{Y}
    \brb\cell{Z}\brb
\erow
\upshape%
}
\tfoot{\lastrule\strut}
%R2B1 % This sexond row is just to ‘fake’ double horizontal lines
\brow
    \tp\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \brb\cell{}\brb
    \cell{}
    \brb\cell{}\brb
    \cell{}
    \brb\cell{}\brb
    \cell{}
    \brb\cell{}\brb
    \cell{}
    \brb\cell{}\brb\tp
    \ht\cals@current@row=2pt
\erow
%R3B2
\brow
    \alignC\cell{0}
    \cell{0}
    \cell{0}
    \brb\cell{0}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
\erow
%R4B3
\brow
    \cell{0}
    \cell{0}
    \cell{0}
    \brb\cell{1}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
\erow
%R5B4
\brow
    \cell{0}
    \cell{0}
    \cell{1}
    \brb\cell{0}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
\erow
%R5B4
\brow
    \bbb\cell{0}
    \cell{0}
    \cell{1}
    \brb\cell{1}\brb
    \cell{1}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{1}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{1}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{0}\bbb\brb
\erow
%R6B5
\brow
    \cell{0}
    \cell{1}
    \cell{0}
    \brb\cell{0}\brb
    \cell{0}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{1}\brb
    \cell{1}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{1}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
\erow
%R7B6
\brow
    \cell{0}
    \cell{1}
    \cell{0}
    \brb\cell{1}\brb
    \cell{0}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{0}\brb
    \cell{0}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{1}\brb
\erow
%R8B7
\brow
    \cell{0}
    \cell{1}
    \cell{1}
    \brb\cell{0}\brb
    \cell{0}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{0}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{1}\brb
    \cell{1}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
\erow
%R9B8
\brow
    \bbb\cell{0}
    \cell{1}
    \cell{1}
    \brb\cell{1}\brb
    \cell{0}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{0}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{0}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{1}\bbb\brb
\erow
%R10B9
\brow
    \cell{1}
    \cell{0}
    \cell{0}
    \brb\cell{0}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{1}\brb
    \cell{1}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{1}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{1}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
\erow
%R11B10
\brow
    \cell{1}
    \cell{0}
    \cell{0}
    \brb\cell{1}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{0}\brb
    \cell{0}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{0}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{0}\brb
\erow
%R12B11
\brow
    \cell{1}
    \cell{0}
    \cell{1}
    \brb\cell{0}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{0}\brb
    \cell{0}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{0}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{1}\brb
\erow
%R13B12
\brow
    \bbb\cell{1}
    \cell{0}
    \cell{1}
    \brb\cell{1}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{0}\brb
    \cell{0}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{0}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{1}\bbb\brb
\erow
%R14B13
\brow
    \cell{1}
    \cell{1}
    \cell{0}
    \brb\cell{0}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{0}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{1}\brb
    \cell{1}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{1}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
\erow
%R15B14
\brow
    \cell{1}
    \cell{1}
    \cell{0}
    \brb\cell{1}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{0}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{0}\brb
    \cell{0}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{1}\brb
\erow
%R16B15
\brow
    \cell{1}
    \cell{1}
    \cell{1}
    \brb\cell{0}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
\erow
%R17B16
\brow
    \bbb\cell{1}
    \cell{1}
    \cell{1}
    \brb\cell{1}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb
    \cell{--}
    \brb\cell{--}\brb\bbb
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par
\end{document}
```

### Tabular, colortbl and hhline

Here is your tabular using `tabular`. I have avoided to overwrite the rules by using [colortabl](https://ctan.org/pkg/colortbl) (through [xcolor](https://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) with table-option) and [hhline](https://ctan.org/pkg/hhline). As you will see, the `hhline`-syntax are complicated. You may simplify the code in the preamble by the syntax `*{<no>}{<col>}` and the body by defining the complicated rules as commands. If you find the heavy rules too heavy, you may reduce `\arrayrulewidth` and `\doublerulesep`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, hhline}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{document}
\setlength\doublerulesep{1pt}{\doublerulesepcolor{black}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c||c|c||c|c||c|c||c|c||}
\hline
\itshape D & \itshape C & \itshape B & \itshape A & \itshape S & \itshape T &\itshape U&\itshape V&\itshape W&\itshape X&\itshape Y&\itshape Z\\
\hhline{>{\doublerulesepcolor{white}}|=|=|=|=%
>{\doublerulesepcolor{black}}||>{\doublerulesepcolor{white}}=|=%
>{\doublerulesepcolor{black}}||>{\doublerulesepcolor{white}}=|=%
>{\doublerulesepcolor{black}}||>{\doublerulesepcolor{white}}=|=%
>{\doublerulesepcolor{black}}||>{\doublerulesepcolor{white}}=|=%
>{\doublerulesepcolor{black}}||>{\doublerulesepcolor{white}}%
}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -- & -- &-- &-- &-- &-- &-- &-- \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -- & -- &-- &-- &-- &-- &-- &-- \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -- & -- &-- &-- &-- &-- &-- &-- \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -- & 1 &-- &-- & 1 &-- & 0 \\
\hhline{>{\doublerulesepcolor{black}}|=|=|=|=||=|=||=|=||=|=||=|=||}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -- & -- & 1 & 1 & -- & 1 &-- \\
\hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -- & -- & 0 & 0 & -- & -- & 1 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -- & -- & 0 &-- & 1 & 1 & -- \\
\hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & -- & -- & 0 & -- & 0 & -- & 1 \\
\hhline{>{\doublerulesepcolor{black}}|=|=|=|=||=|=||=|=||=|=||=|=||}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -- & 1 & 1 &-- & 1 &-- & 1 & -- \\
\hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -- & 0 & 0 &-- & 0 & -- & -- & 1 \\
\hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -- & 0 & 0 &-- & -- & 1 & 1 & -- \\
\hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -- & 0 & 0 &-- & -- & 0 & -- & 1 \\
\hhline{>{\doublerulesepcolor{black}}|=|=|=|=||=|=||=|=||=|=||=|=||}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -- & 0 & -- & 1 & 1 & -- & 1 & -- \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -- & 0 & -- & 0 & 0 & -- & -- & 1 \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -- & -- &-- &-- &-- &-- &-- &-- \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -- & -- &-- &-- &-- &-- &-- &-- \\
\hhline{>{\doublerulesepcolor{black}}|=|=|=|=||=|=||=|=||=|=||=|=||}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your answer it helped me a lot solving my table dilemma ;-)

Comment: @tschinz My pleasure. If it was of any help, you may consider to upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. The package `nicematrix` provides tools to define commands and letter (for use in the preamble of the array) to draw rules with the specification of Tikz. In order to have a perfect junction of the rules, I have adjusted the behavior of `\boldline` with the Tikz parameters `shorten >` and `shorten <`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    custom-line = 
     {
       letter = I ,
       command = normalline ,
       tikz = { line width = 0.4 pt } ,
       total-width = 0.4 pt
     } ,
    custom-line = 
     {
       letter = J ,
       tikz = { line width = 1.2 pt } ,
       total-width = 0.8 pt
     } ,
    custom-line = 
     {
       command = boldline ,
       tikz = { line width = 1 pt , shorten > = -0.2pt , shorten < = -0.4pt } ,
       total-width = 1 pt
     } ,
  }

\begin{NiceTabular}{IcIcIcIcJcIcJcIcJcIcJcIcJ}
\normalline
\RowStyle{\itshape}
D & C & B & A & S & T & U & V & W & X & Y & Z \\
\hline\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -- & -- &-- &-- &-- &-- &-- &-- \\
\normalline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -- & -- &-- &-- &-- &-- &-- &-- \\
\normalline
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -- & -- &-- &-- &-- &-- &-- &-- \\
\normalline
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -- & 1 &-- &-- & 1 &-- & 0 \\
\boldline
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -- & -- & 1 & 1 & -- & 1 &-- \\
\normalline
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -- & -- & 0 & 0 & -- & -- & 1 \\
\normalline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -- & -- & 0 &-- & 1 & 1 & -- \\
\normalline
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & -- & -- & 0 & -- & 0 & -- & 1 \\
\boldline
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -- & 1 & 1 &-- & 1 &-- & 1 & -- \\
\normalline
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -- & 0 & 0 &-- & 0 & -- & -- & 1 \\
\normalline
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -- & 0 & 0 &-- & -- & 1 & 1 & -- \\
\normalline
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -- & 0 & 0 &-- & -- & 0 & -- & 1 \\
\boldline
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -- & 0 & -- & 1 & 1 & -- & 1 & -- \\
\normalline
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -- & 0 & -- & 0 & 0 & -- & -- & 1 \\
\normalline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -- & -- &-- &-- &-- &-- &-- &-- \\
\normalline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -- & -- &-- &-- &-- &-- &-- &-- \\
\boldline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]